# Setting up an Exchange account on Snow Leopard

Tags: email, osx-snow-leopard, exchange

I am trying to setup an Exchange account in the Mail application on Snow Leopard.  I've set it up on my iPhone and it works perfectly.  However, I am unable to do so in the Mail app.  I've entered all identical information, but to no avail.

What troubleshooting steps can i take?